# custom post types - overwrite function in parent theme function.php via child theme

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to create portfolio page using custom post types in child theme. Here's the my [site](http://buildandtest.atspace.cc/index.html) with 'work' page I am trying to convert using custom post types. I found this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-custom-post-types-to-create-a-killer-portfolio--wp-20565) however it is for a parent theme. The tutorial uses pluggable function to add theme support for post thumbnails

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 280, 210, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'screen-shot', 720, 540 ); // Full size screen
```

However my parent theme (twentysixteen) already has such function which is not pluggable

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 1200, 9999 );
```

My question is what would be the correct way to go about child theme in terms of incorporating the above? Should I wrap in `if ( function_exists` statement the parent theme function since I am looking to be able to overwrite it via child them functions.php?

Comment: that usage of `if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { ` is not really pluggable, but rather caring for older versions of WordPress where the function `add_theme_support()` was not yet implemented; the fiunction was introduced in wp2.9.0... how old is your tutorial?

Comment: have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_theme_support/

Comment: Thanks for the info @Michael. Yes its an old tutorial because I was not able to find any other. So I shouldn't be using if ( function_exists in my child theme functions.php? How I can make sure it overwrites parent functions.php?

Comment: try and use  'remove_theme_support()` ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_theme_support/

Comment: thanks again @Michael